# How to create the following loop to get coupon rates for a CDO

Tags: python, finance

I am trying to create a loop that will pick coupons for different trenches of a CDO based on uniform random numbers created by numpy.

if rand < 0.25
 A gets rand * $5

if rand < o.5
 A gets 0.25*$5
 B gets (rand-0.25)*$5

if rand < 0.75
 A gets 0.25*$5
 B gets 0.25*$5
 C gets (rand-0.5)*$5

if rand < 1
  A gets 0.25*$5
  B gets 0.25*$5
  C gets 0.25*$5
  D gets (rand-0.75)*$5

I created a CSV for rands with 20 columns for a 20 bond portfolio.(ranfile1)

and 100,000 rows for scenarios.

```
I created a code up to the third trench without the "D". 

    randfile1=np.random.rand(20,100000)
spots = [0.0211,0.0188,0.0184,0.0187,0.0189,0.0195,0.0201,0.0205,0.0208,0.02120,0.0215,0.0218,0.0221,0.0224,0.0227,0.0229,0.0232,0.0235,0.0238,0.0241]

A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []


a = randfile1[randfile1 < 0.25].sum() * 5
A.append(a)

b = (randfile1[np.logical_and(0.25 <= randfile1, randfile1 < 0.5)] - 0.25).sum()  * 5
B.append(b)
a = np.logical_and(0.25 < randfile1, randfile1 < 0.5).sum() * 1.25
A.append(a)



c = (randfile1[np.logical_and(0.5 <= randfile1, randfile1 < 0.75)] - 0.5).sum()  * 5
C.append(c)
b = np.logical_and(0.5 < randfile1, randfile1 < 0.75).sum() * 1.25
B.append(b)
a = np.logical_and(0.5 < randfile1, randfile1 < 0.75).sum() * 1.25
A.append(a)

d = (randfile1[np.logical_and(0.75 <= randfile1, randfile1 < 1)] - 0.5).sum()  * 5
D.append(d)
c = np.logical_and(0.75 < randfile1, randfile1 < 1).sum() * 1.25
C.append(c)
b = np.logical_and(0.75 < randfile1, randfile1 < 1).sum() * 1.25
B.append(b)
a += np.logical_and(0.75 < randfile1, randfile1 < 1).sum() * 1.25
A.append(a)
```

Comment: When you use enumerate you do not need this line `row = randfile1.values[i]`. When appending to the list your are appending your entire DF instead of the value in row.

Answer (score 1):

[Colab Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18UHGdFxPJtJvYWeoEqYPHZH4bpY1TEGs)

What you are trying to achieve here can be done with advanced indexing, conditions on numpy arrays and Numpy's logical operators.

```
import numpy as np

rand_data = np.random.rand(1, 40) # Generate 40 random number

A = rand_data[rand_data < 0.25].sum() * 5 # Advanced indexing is in use here
# Get the ones between 0 and 0.25 and multiply the sum with 5

# Get the ones larger than 0.25 and smaller than 0.5 apply logical-and to indices
# Get the sum of the elements in those indices and substract 0.25 from each of them
# Finally multiply the sum with 5
B = (rand_data[np.logical_and(0.25 <= rand_data, rand_data < 0.5)] - 0.25).sum()  * 5
# We are interested in the count of values between 0.25 and 0.5
# So no advanced indexing here just get the count on binary values using the sum
# and multiply with 0.25 * 5
A += np.logical_and(0.25 < rand_data, rand_data < 0.5).sum() * 1.25

C = (rand_data[np.logical_and(0.5 <= rand_data, rand_data < 0.75)] - 0.5).sum()  * 5
B += np.logical_and(0.5 < rand_data, rand_data < 0.75).sum() * 1.25
A += np.logical_and(0.5 < rand_data, rand_data < 0.75).sum() * 1.25
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

Comment: Hey, there is a difference in what I require. If you look at the code which I just added you can see I have appended the cashflows to four bins. and those four bins should be in 20 columns in order to be discounted by spots of 20 years.

Comment: Cool, but how can I go about this mate?